# Studies about learning terms in your native language?

Tags: learning, reference-request, educational-psychology, linguistics

I've been thinking about how much time do the Czech biology teachers spend just teaching the Czech terms for the organisms which they probably won't encounter again with, considering the fact that studies use exclusively the latin ones.

But it just came to my mind that maybe it's easier for the brain to remember your native name for the organism and then connect it with the latin name, I've heard some physicists saying that those native-foreign pair words are often [calques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calque) - so apart from the connection with the actual organism you make the connection with the meaning of the word.

But those are just my guesses. Are there any studies on this topic?